# IdentityServer: User starts at Identity Server

Tags: asp.net, identityserver4

In all the examples I've seen, the user starts on the desired website, clicks a Login button, and is redirected to the Identity Server for authentication.

My client would like the user to be able to start at the Login page on the Identity Server, type in their username and password and then be redirected to the desired website.

Is this possible?  How could this be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the ASP.NET Core and the classic AddOpenIdConnect, you must trigger the authentication flow from the client. So that the state/nonce/PKCE security features gets right.

But what you could do is in your client automatically redirect new users or non-authenticated users directly to IdentityServer. That is not so hard to do.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up redirecting to the target website when the user click on Login on the Identity Server.  Then the target website redirects back to the Identity Server with the appropriate ReturnUrl querystring.